# Pasting SQL decimal columns into Excel

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a issue with data formats of Excel and SQL.

I have a column in SQL which is of datatype `DECIMAL(18,0)` and when I am trying to paste the result in SQL..the last 3 digits of the sql result gets replaced by 0 in Excel.

Example:

In SQL the result set has a column called session id and has decimal numbers like

```
119,597,417,242,309,670        
329,621,151,415,350,454       
134,460,940,261,658,890
```

but when I paste it in Excel the numbers look like:

[image]

I tried changing the format in EXCEL to paste as text however, the whole format of the result set gets distorted (and only the first column gets pasted properly without the 0's)

I can't keep casting all columns in SQL from decimal to int as there are way too many columns.

Can you please guide me as to what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric fields in Excel are limited to 15 digits precision.

In SQL Assistant under *Tools / Options / Data Format* you can ask to have large Decimal (and BIGINT) fields displayed as text for just this sort of copy / paste. Or you can tell SQL Assistant to Save As or Export to Excel format.

For other tools you can explicitly FORMAT and CAST the data to VARCHAR in your SELECT so it is retrieved as text.

Comment: Thanks fred! I tried your first option, but it isnt working!:( I clicked the box where in the options tab but after that when I paste back in excel its the same (the last 3 digits get converted into 0)

Comment: Did you re-run the query? This setting applies to new answer sets displayed after the option is set.

Comment: Never mind. Looks like recent versions of Excel are determined to "helpfully" format anything that looks like a number as "numeric". You may need to use Excel's "Paste Using Text Import Wizard" feature instead of a simple Paste. The data should be tab-delimited and you can click on the columns in question and change the format from General to Text. Or use the Save/Export options to create an Excel spreadsheet (which should format these columns as text). Or in your SELECT use something such as `''''||CAST(col AS VARCHAR(25))` to put an apostrophe in front of the text value to make Excel happy.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you can do. I'll list 4. 
Pick whatever suits you best.

1. First paste in a text editor (like notepad), seach/replace there, and paste that.
2. Set the datarange where you're going to paste to "text", and then paste. After that you can search/replace, and change to the correct format.
3. Change the regional settings of Windows to match the data that you have.
4. You can generate formula's from your SQL query, instead of floating point numbers. So generate a text like `=5/10` instead of `0.5` or `0,5`. Excel will pick it up correctly regardless of your regional settings.

Comment: Thanks for replying! In the first one, can you please elaborate? I pasted my result set (with 8 column fields) in Notepad..What do I search & replace now? I am not sure what you mean here..Out of the 8 columns 4 of them are decimal type...should I select those and paste them as text? I tried that and it still gives me same result